# Get keys of 5 bigests value from array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key, max

I have one problem. I must get 5 images which rates are the biggest. I have table which key = image_id and value = average rating.

Below is print_r of this array

```
Array ( ['5'] => 5.00 ['4'] => 3.05 ['12'] => 3.00 ['11'] => 4.00 ['21'] => 2.11 ['53'] => 4.44 )
```

For example

```
['5'] => 5.00
```

means that img which id = '5' have rating 5.00

Expected output 2 Arrays ($id and $rating)

```
Array ( [0] => '5' [1] => '53' [2] => '11' [3] => '4' [4] => '12' )
Array ( [0] => '5.00' [1] => '4.44' [2] => '4.00' [3] => '3.05' [4] => '3.00' )
```

Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [arsort();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) and [array_slice();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

You can also avoid making 2 separate arrays with functions like [array_keys();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_values();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
// Original array
$array = array(
    5 => 5.00,
    4 => 3.05,
    12 => 3.00,
    11 => 4.00,
    21 => 2.11,
    53 => 4.44
);

// Sort array & maintain keys
arsort($array);

// Now get the first 5 elements, keeping the keys
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 5, true);

// IDs
print_r(array_keys($array));

// Ratings
print_r(array_values($array));
```

Comment: Question does not mention anything about SQL so it should not be main part of an answer. Besides `array_slice` reorders keys in returned array, so you should correct your example and mention `array_keys` / `array_values`

Comment: "I have table which key = image_id and value = average rating." likely refers to an SQL table. Also, array_slice can preserve keys if needed. I realized after I posted my answer that OP doesn't care about maintaining array keys (hence his desired result set), so I replaced my original sort function with the correct one.

Comment: In polish language we have same translation for `table` and `array`, so mentioning `table` does not necessarily mean SQL table, its just OP bad choice of words. As for example you need to preserve keys, since OP wants one array of scores and one of IDs (that will be lost)

Comment: I know nothing about the polish language, but I'll keep that in mind for the future. As far as maintaining keys goes, I failed to think about that because I normally set my stuff up like I do in my updated answer, so I don't have to worry about it. Thanks for providing clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) or [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)?